# Add json object to json data fetched from database in php

Tags: php, json

In database JSON data is stored in below way:

```
{"name":"abc","score":5}
```

Now everytime I want to add json object with different name and score to same json data as :

```
{"name":"abc","score":5},{"name":"efg","score":8},{"name":"xyz","score":6}
```

> Right now I have tried this code

```
$database_data = $row['JSONstring']; //fetched json string from database
$json_decode_data = json_decode($database);

array_push($json_decode_data, $new_json_string); //data to append to database data
$updated_json_data = json_encode($json_decode_data); // at last encode the update json data
```

But this don't work and throws a warning : Parameter 1 is an object.

How do solve it ?

Comment: Try with array_merge() function instead of array_push

Comment: pass `true` as 2nd parameter to `json_decode` if you want `$json_decode_data` to be an array
`$json_decode_data = json_decode($database, true)`;

Comment: Its not working I have tried different ways but still required result is not achieved. @vnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with all the answer and comments given here I got the required answer. So I appreciate all your help.

In my question starting, the first JSON String format is invalid:

```
{"name":"abc","score":5}
```

Instead of this, it would be :

`[{"name":"abc","score":5}]`

Required JSON data's format would be:

```
[{"name":"abc","score":5},{"name":"efg","score":8},{"name":"xyz","score":6}]
```

And this is achieved by array_merge() function as follows:

> Code to append json object to json object string

```
//fetched json string from database
ie.[{"name":"abc","score":5}]
$database_data = $row['JSONstring'];

//decode both string the database data string and the new one which is to be merged
$json_decode_database_data = json_decode($database_data, true);
$json_decode_new_data = json_decode($database_data, true);

//merge both the decoded array by array_merge() 
$required_json_data = array_merge($json_decode_data, $new_json_string); 

//at last encode required json data
$updated_json_data = json_encode($required_json_data); 

// You will get required json data
[{"name":"abc","score":5},{"name":"efg","score":8},{"name":"xyz","score":6}]
```